# Horizontal ul with pseudo-elements based on flex-box

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to separate my `ul` with separators (which should be `16px` height).
the `font-size` of my `li` is also `16px`.

But… the separators are actually much bigger than the text for some reason.

Please see the snippet.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello1</li>
  <li>hello2</li>
  <li>hello3</li>
  <li>hello4</li>
  <li>hello5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well if you add 5px padding on the top and the bottom, that is not really much of a surprise now is it?

Comment: sorry, a typo ... meant to be 8px which adds up to 16px

Comment: No, meant to be _less_, not _more_, if you want to _reduce_ their height.

Comment: yes, but i wanted to understand why 16px of vertical padding,and zero content,  adds up to more than this eventually.

Comment: Because you're adding padding to an item that is already taking up 16px - so the total will be 32px. Look what happens when `font-size` is 0 --> https://jsfiddle.net/aks0cfc3/

Comment: Because “zero content” does not mean zero height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative approach using `border` on the `li`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  font-size: 16px;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello1</li>
  <li>hello2</li>
  <li>hello3</li>
  <li>hello4</li>
  <li>hello5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would say in advance that I didn't see your answers and comments before posting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm back...

Declare a `display: inline-block;` rule to the pseudo-element `li:before`, and adjust height and padding.

```
li:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 0px 1px;
    margin: 0 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 0px 1px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello1</li>
  <li>hello2</li>
  <li>hello3</li>
  <li>hello4</li>
  <li>hello5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand why it has height more than `16px` then it's simple:

Your pseudoelement has `display: inline` by default. So its height is based on `font-size` + `padding`s. If you would set `display: inline-block` for `li:before` it will take `16px` as you wish. Also setting `font-size: 0` will also give `16px` height. Demo:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  font-size: 16px;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block; /* new */
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello1</li>
  <li>hello2</li>
  <li>hello3</li>
  <li>hello4</li>
  <li>hello5</li>
</ul>
```

But I would recommend to use flexbox, just make your `li` as flex-container, this will make flex-items behave as a blocks. Demo:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  font-size: 16px;
  /* make li as flex-container */
  display: flex;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 8px 1px;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello1</li>
  <li>hello2</li>
  <li>hello3</li>
  <li>hello4</li>
  <li>hello5</li>
</ul>
```

Consider changing padding alignment to border. In flexbox approach you don't need to set height for your `li:before`, because flex items will stretch by default:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  font-size: 16px;
  /* make li as flex-container */
  display: flex;
}

li:before {
  content: '';
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  margin: 0 8px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>hello1</li>
  <li>hello2</li>
  <li>hello3</li>
  <li>hello4</li>
  <li>hello5</li>
</ul>
```